# Need to recover RAID0 disks from failed linux box

Tags: raid, software-raid, dd, mdadm

I have two drives from a failed old Linux box that were configured as RAID0.

I have created two dd image files using the following commands on my Mac:

```
dd if=/dev/disk3 of=disk0.img.dd bs=512
dd if=/dev/disk3 of=disk1.img.dd bs=512
```

(Input "files" are the same because I connected the drives via USB one at a time. The images are of two disks for sure.)

How can I read them in to a software raid, either on my Mac or a VMware machine, to recover the files?

I know very little about disks, btw.

Comment: So you have 2 copies of the same disk?

Comment: no... I just have one usb reader.

Comment: So I read both disks in one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `losetup(8)` to create block devices from the files. These can be marked read-only so you cannot accidentally overwrite part of the files.

Then, use `mdadm(8)` normally to assemble the array. If the disk images contain superblocks, a regular `mdadm --assemble --scan` should do, otherwise you need to specify the geometry.